# Java3D Won't Show Me Anything

Tags: java, java-3d

Help! When I try to start my .class file, i see the application popup, then exit. I don't get to see my precious work!!! Can someone look at the code below and tell me what I did wrong?

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;

import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;

public class Hello3d {

public Hello3d()

{

    SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();

    BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();

    group.addChild(new ColorCube(0.3));

    universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();

    universe.addBranchGraph(group);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Hello3d();
        }
    });
}

} // end of class Hello3d
```

Answer (score 1):

You set up your scene correctly as far as I can tell, but you didn't create any means to show it to the user (windows, canvas, etc).

From your code, I'm assuming you've been following [this tutorial](http://www.java3d.org/starting.html), is it correct? Check [Java 3D and the User Interface](http://www.java3d.org/userinterface.html) (a few pages ahead in the same site) to learn how to do that.

Comment: @mrgibsonbr , this script is for an Applet. How can I transform it into one for an application

Comment: The [`MainFrame`](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.3.2/com/sun/j3d/utils/applet/MainFrame.html) class allows you to view the applet's contents in a window, if you follow the example as it is it should work fine as an application. In principle, I believe you could also replace the `Applet` for a `Frame` and it would work as well (it's been long since I last used Java 3D, so I can't remember for sure).